# Is dir='rtl' supported on XBOX UWP webview?

Tags: css, webview, uwp, uwp-xaml, scss-mixins

Currently, I'm trying to use my web source URL to develop an UWP webview app on VS2022.

In my web source URL we're using the different stylings for dir='rtl' for arabic language so when I run the code on the normal browser everything is working fine. But when I run it on XBOX using the local/remote machine method the 'rtl' styles are not working as expected.

I've tried making a lot of changes to CSS but still facing the issue with the styling part used by the dir='rtl'. All the text is shown from right to left but the image styles for -webkit-mask-image is not working as expected.

```
@include rtl(
  -webkit-mask-image,
  -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 25%),
  -webkit-linear-gradient(right, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 25%)
);
@include rtl(
  mask-image,
  linear-gradient(right, #060011 34%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 18%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%),
  linear-gradient(left, #060011 34%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 18%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%)
);
```

Here the styles were given as the image should get blurred on the right side and should visible properly on the left side. But when I run this on local/remote machine the total image is getting blurred.

Is this method supported on XBOX UWP WebView? If not is there any work around that has to be used to make this work. (**I'm using normal webview to develop this UWP not webview2**)

Thanks in advance. Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you wait until the end of this year MS Xbox dev team should be adding support for Webview2 control on Xbox. Then you can use `rtl` inside of Webview2 instead of older Webview control.

[MS Learn UWP - Webview2 Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2)

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your response I tried with WebView2 method which you've mentioned but as you mentioned there's no support to deploy UWP apps on xbox yet since we need to release the app to store I can't go with this method until WebView2 is released on Xbox.

Comment: FWIW my contact at MS says the plan is to have it available by Q4 this year.  If you want to play with it the preview nuget pkg is out there: [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/1.0.1988-prerelease?_src=template)